# How to not repeteadly insert data in sql tables

Tags: sql

Good evening. My teacher said we should use this syntax everytime we input data in a table:

```
drop database a15roban
create database a15roban
use a15roban
Create table person .... ()
```

I have a weak table called Skees where i inserted that a person is assigned to a specific Skee, such as SkeeNr3 and so forth, but everytime i run a query it gets inserted again, so when i run the query select Skee.Name from Skee where SkeeNrID = 3 i get the person who owns them a bunch of times. Any solutions?

Comment: Please provide more details. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What query are you running multiple times?

Comment: Well you certainly don't want to drop the database and recreate it every time you ruin an insert or update Query!!!  Please do not think that is an acceptable thing to do or you will get fired the first time you do it in a real job. However we can't help you without seeing the actual insert code you are using.

Comment: nuke and pave is a valid approach when inserting into a table depending on the context but to drop a database and recreated every time you insert seems a bit extreme don't you think? Are you sure that's what you were told to do?

Comment: ^^ What @HLGEM stated, we need more information.

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should take heed to the comments to your question regarding dropping the entire database.

I think what could help you based on my interpretation of your question is to add a unique constraint to the `SkeeNrID` field in your table.

Without knowing which DBMS you are using, I can't be 100% certain about the syntax, but it is likely to look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
SkeeNrID INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
-- [other fields]
);
```

or even:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
SkeeNrID INT PRIMARY KEY, --cannot be null and must be unique
-- [other fields]
);
```

When a duplicate `SkeeNrID` insert is attempted, you should get an error. This, in the very least, should help you identify where/why the core of the problem exists.